# where does ''options" come from in this JavaScript block of code?

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, html-select

**[i have this code from MDN which i am trying to understand !](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)**

**first:>**

where does '**options**' came from in this block :-

`for (var i = 0; i < selectObject.options.length; i++) {
    if (selectObject.options[i].selected)`*

**second:>**

```
  why it 'options' does work fine inside the function and not work outside the function
```

---

Here is the code-

```
<form name="selectForm">
  <p>
    <label for="musicTypes">Choose some music types, then click the button below:</label>
    <select id="musicTypes" name="musicTypes" multiple="multiple">
      <option selected="selected">R&B</option>
      <option>Jazz</option>
      <option>Blues</option>
      <option>New Age</option>
      <option>Classical</option>
      <option>Opera</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p><input id="btn" type="button" value="How many are selected?" /></p>
</form>

<script>
function howMany(selectObject) {
  var numberSelected = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < selectObject.options.length; i++) {
    if (selectObject.options[i].selected) {
      numberSelected++;
    }
  }
  return numberSelected;
}

var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('Number of options selected: ' + howMany(document.selectForm.musicTypes));
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `options` are part of HTML DOM and are responsible for selecting `options` elements inside the specified `select` element

2) It does work outside of function on any select element, but i'm assuming you are trying to use s`electObject` outside of the function, which violates variable scope.

Read more:

[1] https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_select_options.asp

[2] https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: "part of native javascript" — no, it isn't. It is part of the HTML DOM.

Comment: Pardon me, you are completly right. Seems i'm not awaken yet today. Corrected :)

Comment: Thank you so much , have a nice day sir